# palindrome class -- NameError: name 'is_palindrome' is not defined

Tags: python, class, palindrome

I get the error

> "NameError: name 'is_palindrome' is not defined"

I found this easy problem on a website, that asks to create a class
named `Palindrome` and within it a function named `is_palindrome` to check a given  word and return `True` if it's palindrome and `False` otherwise
it should be done using a class and a static method ( so I can't remove them )
the code is below.

```
class Palindrome:
    @staticmethod
    def is_palindrome(s):
        return len(s) < 2 or s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])

word = input()
print(Palindrome.is_palindrome(word))
```

I have solved the question by removing the class declaration 
 other methods like

```
return word==word[::-1]
```

but I am trying to understand the problem with the above code why when I include it in a class I get this error

> "NameError: name 'is_palindrome' is not defined"

Comment: `return len(s) < 2 or s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])` looks fisshhyy

Comment: I really don't know how this benefits from using a static method in a class rather than simply a function.

Comment: @RobinZigmond as I said in the question the class and static method was declared by the site itself I can't remove it (and if I do it worked) so I am trying to understand why it doesn't work when it is included in a class

Comment: @DirtyBit I am aware of the indentations in Python so I am sure the code indented correctly ( if you see anything wrong please tell me which line )

Comment: @DirtyBit actually it just checks if the length of the world is less than 2 ( which is palindrome by default ) and if it's >2 then check the 1st character and the last character if they are equal or not (and keep slicing it until its length is less than 2 )

Answer (score 2):

Although, I do not see how the method in a class or being a static helps, but here is the fix:

```
class Palindrome:
    @staticmethod
    def is_palindrome(s):
        return len(s) < 2 or s[0] == s[-1] and Palindrome.is_palindrome(s[1:-1])

word = input("Enter your word: ")
print(Palindrome.is_palindrome(word))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter your word: ROTAVATOR
True
```

**EDIT**:

If you do not want to get tangled up in class, assuming there is nothing else your're already doing:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return len(s) < 2 or s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])

word = input("Enter your word: ")
print(is_palindrome(word))
```

**EDIT 3**:

Another way:

```
class Palindrome:
    def is_palindrome(self, s):
        return len(s) < 2 or s[0] == s[-1] and self.is_palindrome(s[1:-1])

word = input("Enter your word: ")
p_Obj = Palindrome()
print(p_Obj.is_palindrome(word))
```

Comment: do I understand from your solution (which worked ) that I can't call the method that I have created inside the class directly, but I have to use class_name.method?

Comment: and the class and static method has no use it was already declared by the site itself

Comment: @Serilena remove the static method, create a object of the class, call the method with that object, pass a `self` in the method `is_palindrome()` and it should do as well.

Comment: @Serilena kindly check the edit 3 and if it helped you may accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Comment: @Serilena Also I recommend reading: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: the first solution actually solves the problem thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the class Palindrome. Just have

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return len(s) < 2 or s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

Comment: as I have said in my question It did work when I remove the class but I want to understand why it doesn't when I include it within a class but thx anyway